# UISlider Finished Changing

Tags: ios

I have a slider that when it begins to change the values, another label shows up (lets the user see what they are doing). The only problem is that I need to know when the user has finished editing the slider so I can make that UILabel go away again. Is there a way to do this? The code below shows what I do when the sliders value begins to change. Thank you for you help!

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    tipPercentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", ([sender value] * 100)];
    tipPercentLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", ([sender value] * 100)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [tipPercentLabel setAlpha:0.3];
    [tipPercentLabel2 setAlpha:1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [self performSelector:@selector(autoTipCalc) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
```

Comment: I think it's hard to determing when the user has finished sliding... Has he really finished sliding or is he just pausing... So what exactlty is "finished"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already added one target/action pair for `UIControlEventValueChanged`, all you need to do is call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` again with a different selector and a control event of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` (or any other that you're interested in).

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused. So I would just say addTarget:action:forControlEvents: then whatever I want to do here? I am so sorry.

Comment: Somewhere you have [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged]; ? Or you're doing it in XIB?

Comment: Yeah I am doing it in XIB. :)

Comment: Okay but then I added     [mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged]; to my viewDidLoad. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, so you can also do it in code, probably in `viewDidLoad`. Add: `[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChangesCompleted:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` (set whatever selector is appropriate for your code).

Comment: Okay great got it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add target to your slider as if you would to `UIButon` handling `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` (do it also for outside). Optionally or alternatively you could perform a selector after delay each time the value changes to check when the slider value has last changed and remove the label if it has taken long enough.

Comment: Also it would be best to handle touch down to display the label in the first place..